# Port and url error in heroku app

Tags: java, web-services, heroku, cloud, port

I made a webservice that publish a wsdl file , here is the code

```
Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:"+args[0]+"/main/webServ", new WebServiceImpl());
```

and here is the procfile

```
worker: java -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* com.example.Publisher $PORT
```

there is no error in the log file and I got the port number from there lets say its "7435".
and when I run :

```
telnet whispering-beyond-3102.heroku.com
```

I got nothing

how can I access the webserice url ? , I tried to go to:

```
http://whispering-beyond-3102.heroku.com:7435/run/java/main/webServ?wsdl
```

I get no output

what URL should I use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are exposing a web service, you'll want to be defining a `web` process in your `Procfile` instead of a `worker` process. This will tell Heroku to inject the `$PORT` environment variable on app start up and route web requests to your app on that port. Web requests from the Internet to your app should be on the default 80 (or 443 for HTTPS) and then Heroku will route the request to your app on the provided `$PORT`. Once you fix the `Procfile`, you should be able to access your web service at (on default port 80):

```
http://whispering-beyond-3102.heroku.com/run/java/main/webServ?wsdl
```

Comment: how should the procfile look like?